# Bootstrap 3 - Carousel as background with fading transition

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use Bootstrap Carousel as background for my site. I succefully added standard carousel as background, but all codes or tutorial for making fade transition fails. This is what I made for now:

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

...

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide fill" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div id="first" class="fill"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div id="second" class="fill"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="signin-form">
            <form class="form-signin" method="post" id="login-form">
                <h2 class="form-signin-heading" align="center">Login</h2>
                <hr />
                <div id="error" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User" name="user_name" id="user" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="user_password" id="user_password" />
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="btn-login" id="btn-login">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Accedi
                    </button> 
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>


<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cherry+Swash);
body, html{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:#222;
    font-family: 'Cherry Swash', trebuchet ms, cursive; 
    font-size:1.5em
}
a{color:#930; text-decoration:none}

.form-signin {
    max-width: 500px;
    padding: 19px 29px 29px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    margin-top:1%;
    background-color: #fff; -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)"; 
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.7);

    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
       -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);

    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color:#990000;
    font-weight:lighter;

    padding:1em; 
    border-radius:15px; 
    box-shadow:4px 4px 10px 0 rgba(20,20,20,.6); 
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #fff
}

.form-signin .form-signin-heading{
    color:#00A2D1;
}
.form-signin input[type="text"],
.form-signin input[type="password"],
.form-signin input[type="email"] {
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 45px;
    padding: 7px 9px;
}


.signin-form, .body-container
{
    margin-top:110px;
}

#myCarousel{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-1;
}
.item,.active{
    height:100%;
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
}
.carousel-inner{
    height:100%;
    }
.fill{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
}
#first{
    background-image: url('../../images/1.jpg');
}
#second{
    background-image: url('../../images/2.jpg');
}
```

JS:

```
$("#myCarousel").carousel({
    interval: 500,
    pause: 'none'
    });
```

Fill class is used to fit the image in the window.

I tried [this](https://codepen.io/transportedman/pen/NPWRGq) solution but I'm not able to run it properly, maybe the problem is due to .css mess up and mixed something I didn't have to. Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I take the code from the attached codepen and apply it to the code you've provided it all works fine, however, there are a couple of bits that need tweaking.

`carousel-fade` class needs adding to the main carousel element to ensure that the below css works correctly.

I've also increased the interval in the js file. When left at 500 the switching of slides was interrupting the fade animation causing a choppy effect.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Add 'carousel-fade' class to the carousel element -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide fill carousel-fade">
```

**CSS (Source: https://codepen.io/transportedman/pen/NPWRGq)**

```
/* Add this to the bottom of your CSS */
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
  opacity: 0;
  transition-property: opacity;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
}

@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
// Change interval to 2000
$("#myCarousel").carousel({
    interval: 2000,
    pause: 'none'
});
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/raptorkraine/pen/MEgjwe

Comment: It works! Maybe I was editing bad .css file. Indeed carousel interval was 500 for testing only.